# Just return result that satisfies a date condition in solr?

Tags: date, datetime, solr, conditional-statements

I have table `television`, it has field `createdDate`.

Now I want to take all televisions which are created: |NOW - createdDate| < 10 (days), for example.

How can I do this in solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [date-math-now-and-filter-queries](http://searchhub.org/dev/2012/02/23/date-math-now-and-filter-queries/)

You can create query `fq=createdDate:[NOW-10DAY TO NOW]` to filter out the documents.
The debug query would be created as `createdDate:[1344059617705 TO 1344923617705]`

In solrconfig.xml you can use the below with the request handler :-

> ```
>   <lst name="appends">
>      <str name="fq">createdDate:[NOW-10DAY TO NOW]</str>
>    </lst>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use fq as parameter in url, it works fine. But when I use fq field in solrconfig.xml, it doesn't work if I don't pass fq as parameter in url. May you help me?

Comment: I realize that I must restart my server. Thanks!